# Cannot run Selenium Basic from VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

VBA returns an error whenever I attempt to run even the most basic code.  Examples and templates included with the Selenium Basic install don't work.  This code errors at the second line:

```
Dim obj As Selenium.EdgeDriver
Set obj = New Selenium.EdgeDriver

obj.Start
obj.Get "http://www.google.com"
```

Error:

```
Run-time error '-2146232576 (80131700)':
Automation error
```

Software versions:

```
Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19044 Build 19044
Excel 2021 MSO (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20128) 64-bit
SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0
Edge Version 99.0.1150.55 (Official build) (64-bit)
```

I downloaded the x64 version of the Edge webdriver from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) then renamed it **edgedriver.exe** and put it here: C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic

I also enabled the Selenium Type Library

Comment: Try installing office version 32bit, not 64bit. I remember I found a lot of issues when used 64bit